# App Engine Session Timeout

Tags: python, google-app-engine

When do user sessions (Users API in Python) timeout when logging in with Google Accounts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is configurable in the dashboard, under Administration -> Application Settings.

The default is 1 day, but you can set it as high as 2 weeks.